# Unable to display list in one single line

Tags: html

The background image was works finally.But I am unable to display the list in one single line using the below code.  The below code displays like "Computer Architecture" in the first line and display "Download" in the second line

```
<ul id="verticalmenu" class="glossymenu">
<li><b><big>Computer Architecture</big></b><a href="#">(Download)</a><hr>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Lecture1</a>
<li><a href="#">Lecture2</a>
</ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Do you have any CSS to share with us?

Comment: It works in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fLW8J/

Comment: Yes I have CSS file. please find the below CSS code

Comment: .glossymenu, .glossymenu li ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 500px; /*WIDTH OF MAIN MENU ITEMS*/
border: 1px groove;
}

.glossymenu li{
position: relative;
}

.glossymenu li a{
/*background:url(glossyback.gif) repeat-x bottom left;*/
font: bold 12px calibri;
color: #A52A2A;
display: block;
width: auto;
padding: 5px 0;
padding-left: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
}